# Possible results of integer xor in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Is it guaranteed that `(2 ^ 32) == 34`?

Comment: What other value(s) do you think it could have?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm - I guess it might depend on the representation of `int` on the system in question? I'm not sure though.

Comment: Is `2 + 32` guaranteed to be `34`? Is `2 | 32` guaranteed to be `34`?

Comment: @doug - I would say "yes" for `2 + 34` and for `2 | 32` I would expect the answer to be the same as the answer to my question. The distinction being that + doesn't depend on the bit-wise representation of the values, but other operations may.

Comment: @BeeOnRope When you make a change in your question that could invalidate existing answer, **you must write it clearly in the question** so that people that answered before the change won't get penalized.

Comment: Now it does not matters anymore as he saw the change before he get downvote

Comment: A language requiring such a question is... pathological.

Answer (score 11):

**In C++20, yes.**

Here's how [`[expr.xor]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.xor) defines it:

> Given the coefficients *x<sub>i</sub>* and *y<sub>i</sub>* of the base-2 representation ([basic.fundamental]) of the converted operands *x* and *y*, the coefficient *r<sub>i</sub>* of the base-2 representation of the result *r* is 1 if either (but not both) of  *x<sub>i</sub>* and *y<sub>i</sub>* are 1, and 0 otherwise.

And [`[basic.fundamental]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental) covers what a base-2 representation means:

> Each value *x* of an unsigned integer type with width *N* has a unique representation *x = x<sub>0</sub>2<sup>0</sup> + x<sub>1</sub>2<sup>1</sup> + … + x<sub>N-1</sub>2<sup>N-1</sup>*, where each coefficient *x<sub>i</sub>* is either 0 or 1; this is called the *base-2 representation* of *x*. The base-2 representation of a value of signed integer type is the base-2 representation of the congruent value of the corresponding unsigned integer type.

In short, it doesn't really matter how it's done "physically": the operation *must* satisfy the more abstract, arithmetic notion of base-2 (whether this matches the bits in memory or not; of course in reality it will) and so XOR is entirely well-defined.

However, this was not always the case. The wording was introduced by [P1236R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1236r1.html), to make it crystal clear how integer operations behave and to abstract away the kind of wooly notion of a "bit".

In C++11, all we knew is that signed integers must follow *"A positional representation for integers that uses the binary digits 0 and 1, in which the values represented by successive bits are additive, begin with 1, and are multiplied by successive integral power of 2, except perhaps for the bit with the highest position*" (footnote 49; be advised that this is non-normative).

This gets us most of the way there, actually, but the specific wording in `[expr.xor]` wasn't there: all we knew is that *"the result is the bitwise exclusive OR function of the operands"*. At this juncture, whether that refers to a sufficiently commonly understood operation is really up to you. You'll be hard-pressed to find a dissenting opinion on what this operation was permitted to do, mind you.

So:

**In C++11, YMMV.**

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that all this is C++20 wording. The question is tagged C++11 after all.

Comment: @bogdan Fair. I'll cross check in a mo.

Comment: Thanks, interesting to see that it is explicitly defined in terms of base-2!

Comment: @BeeOnRope And kind of terrifying that it _isn't_ in any as-yet-released standard :D

Comment: We did have [basic.fundamental]/7 in C++11. Not as detailed, but I think it covers OP's example. By reference to an external dictionary, in a comment... :-)

Comment: @bogdan Huh, true.

Comment: Should the second quote, which is about unsigned integers, be about signed integers instead?

Comment: @BeeOnRope I took a bit of a shortcut - will add

Comment: @bogdan There that should do it

Answer (score 7):

**yes**

Or at least for the unedited version of the question when it was written as:

`2 ^ 32 == 34`

Given that the relational operator `==` has a [higher precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than bitwise XOR `^`, the expression is evaluated as:

`2 ^ (32 == 34)`

that is: `2 ^ 0`

which is by definition `2` and thus `true`

Comment: Cute… but I don't think that's what the OP intended to ask. :P

Comment: tell the assert statement that

Comment: The OP is not an assert statement

Comment: Heh, you got me. That said, I think even when reduced to `2 ^ 0` the question remains, right? Or maybe 0 is a special case. Anyways, I added the parens.

Comment: Agreed, I just couldn't resist, don't take it too seriously though :)

Comment: :) - btw there is some controversy over the edit to add the parens: see the comments on the question. I'd add the requested note if you prefer.

Comment: @BeeOnRope Add the note if you like. This was more like a joke, but I don't want to distract too much from your original question

Answer (score 1):

No matter how the values are represented internally, the result of `2 ^ 32` is `34`. The `^` operator means a binary XOR and the result you must get if you do that operation correctly is independent of how you do the operation.

The same is true of `2 + 32`. You can represent 2 and 32 in binary, in decimal, or any other way you want, but the result you get had better be the way you represent 34, whatever that is.

Comment: Agreed for the most part, but xor isn't really defined in terms of integers, is it? It is defined for a single bit, or for bit strings. Would your answer be the same for `-1 | 1` or `~1`? In all these cases I think you need to define a mapping from integers to bit strings to answer. Addition obviously requires no such mapping.

Comment: To be fair, `+` is widely understood in mathematical terms, whereas `^` is literally a bitwise operation so the notion that its results may depend on a bit representation is not crazy.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if the standard formally defines exclusive or, but it's a well known operation with a consistent definition. The one thing that is explicitly left out of the standard is the mapping of integer numbers to bits. Your assertion would hold for the commonly used twos-complement representation and the uncommon ones-complement.

Comment: "The representations of integral types shall define values by use of a pure binary numeration system." But even if that weren't required, I'd say "the bitwise exclusive OR function" has to mean the common definition in terms of sums of powers of two.

Comment: _The one thing that is explicitly left out of the standard is the mapping of integer numbers to bits_ : well, yes - that's the crux of the matter, isn't it?

Comment: @aschepler xor has nothing to do with sums. It's a bitwise operation, which means you can't evaluate it until you know how integers are mapped to bits. I stand by my statement, the standard does not define that mapping because they wanted to be able to handle odd mappings like ones complement.

Comment: @BeeOnRope the standard attempts to be as universally applicable as possible, so the mapping of integers to bits is left unspecified. 99% of the processors you'll find use twos complement, so you're usually safe making that assumption. But it's not guaranteed.

Comment: @BeeOnRope And that's exactly why the answer is perfectly correct!! "The one thing that is explicitly left out of the standard is the mapping of integer numbers to bits" is THE correct answer, not the crux.

Comment: @Handy - so is the answer yes or no? Because this is a yes or no question

Comment: @BeeOnRope the answer I tried to portray is that you don't know - the standard isn't clear enough to pin it down with certainty. Lightness Races answer does introduce a couple of things that make a difference though.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: The answer is no: There is no guarantee in c++11.

Comment: My "sum" comment just referred to how one could mathematically define bitwise operations: in Lightness's answer, "the base-2 representation" relies on noting that a non-negative integer is uniquely represented as a sum of distinct powers of two. (I still think the C++11 wording implies everything the C++20 wording does, at least for unsigned operands, but C++20 is just much more explicit about it.)