# Is ~i really equivalent to i != -1?

Tags: c++, bitwise-not

How does `~i` work in C++?

I just noticed it is equivalent to `i != -1`, but I'm not certain about that.

```cpp
int arr[3] {1, 2, 3};
int n = 3;
for (int i = n - 1; ~i; i--) {
    cout << arr[i] << ' ';
}
```

It printed the array in reverse.

Comment: The `~` operator simply inverts all bits of the operand.

Comment: `~` flips all the bits. In two's complement, `-1` is when all the bits are set. So when you flip all the bits, all the bits are reset, which gives you `0`. This is the cast to `false` for your `for` loop.

Comment: @StoryTeller: The answer to this question is not found _anywhere_ on that page.

Comment: Also two answers in the comments section. Sigh.

Comment: @Blaze: Not if `i` is unsigned.

Comment: This is an obfuscated way to write the test `i != -1` in a very implementation dependent way.

Comment: Is this part of an exercise? Nobody should ever write code like this in real world programs.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - So you hypothesize `~` is not explained on that page at all? Interesting.

Comment: Before C++20, they are not portably equivalent since some platforms may have 1s complement `int` (although I'm not aware of such a platform which supports modern C++).  C++20 requires `int` to be 2s complement, so now they are equivalent.

Comment: @Jabberwocky In competitive programming, you will see more than that.

Comment: @HossamKamil Aren't optimisers allowed in competitive programming?

Comment: I guess it helps in [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)...

Comment: @StoryTeller None of it talks about != -1 or whether the two are equivalent.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`~` is the bitwise NOT operator. `~i` is 0 if and only if `i` has 1 in all its bits. Whether -1 has all bits 1 depends on how signed numbers are represented on the system. In two's complement representation, -1 is represented with all bits 1, so on such systems `~(-1) == 0`. Neither in one's complement, nor in sign-and-magnitude does that hold true.

Therefore, the answer is no; not on all systems. That said, two's complement is fairly ubiquitous in modern machines (everything made since the 90's), and on such systems, the answer is yes. Regardless of the sign representation however, `i != -1` is much more readable.

Comment: N.B. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56589637/560648 Different operation I know but almost certainly the same applies. That is, guaranteed as-if-it-were-two's-complement from C++20, and pretty-much-implied-to-be-required-anyway before that

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What do you mean by "pretty-much-implied-to-be-required-anyway"? There's no requirement for operations to behave as-if-it-were-two's-complement other than operations on fixed width integers until C++20.

Comment: Please click on the link provided

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Can you be more specific. I cannot find the part that explains it. Except for the quote from `[basic.fundamental]`, which has the wording from C++20 that doesn't apply to pre C++20.

Comment: There are two large paragraphs explaining the C++11 behaviour. You can find them beginning with the text "In C++11, "

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit And which part of it explains "pretty-much-implied-to-be-required-as-if-it-were-two's-complement"?

Comment: The part that gives the definition of how signed integers were required to work?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The one that applies equally well to most signed number representations that I know of, rather than only to 2's complement?

Answer (score 5):

`~i` is bitwise NOT operator. I.e. it inverts every bit in `i`.
-1 is represented binary as every bit of number being set to 1, inverting every bit to 0 gets you 0. And when checking integer in place where `bool` is expected 0 is treated as `false` and any other number as `true`.

So, in this particular case yes, `~i` is equivalent with `i != -1`.

Comment: You should mention that the integer representation is implementation dependent... There are no guarantees `-1` is represented with all bits set to 1.

Comment: It's represented like that in a 2's complement system. C++ (still) supports other number representations (though those aren't common anymore). I suggest you expand on that point a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Because your i variable from for loop is of type int, which is defined as signed integer, and as such in twos complement, its binary representation of value -1 is all bits set, what means all bits are 1. On other side, bitwise negation of all ones is all zeros, and that is what you need, loop to execute until i>=0 or i!=-1, since you decrementing i. In that context of bitwise operations on sign values on system has twos complement binary representation of int, yes, it is the same.